# Manual escaping in Doctrine

Tags: sql, security, doctrine

When you're writing native SQL statements with Doctrine, how are you supposed to escape input? In my experience, `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't work.

Comment: prepared statment in doctrine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093428/doctrine-raw-sql-and-prepared-statements

Comment: I know about that already. I'm talking about native SQL statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `mysql_real_escape_string()` is used properly it works great. Parameterized libraries like ADODB and PDO would not work without it.   I strongly recommend using PDO.

Comment: Since reading this I've discovered that `Doctrine_Manager::connection()` is a PDO instance, so if, for example, you have an instance of that called `$conn`, you can do `$conn->quote($value)`.

Comment: Beware for the quote function! It does not escape the quotes like mysql_real_escape_string but returns the given data quoted, e.g. you call quote('check') and the return value is 'check' including single quotes.